# Google Console for Brand Accounts / Getting the OAuth 2.0 Client Secret for Youtube Brand Account?

Tags: api, oauth, youtube, google-api

**Question**
Is there a way to access the google console of a brand account?  I can get a refresh token and the client_id via oauth playground, but I still need to get the client secret to auth on behalf of the brand account.

**Use case / Backstory**
I'm utilizing the youtube api to automate uploading user submitted content.  Everything works fine, and so far so good.

I've now reached the point where I want to give other people access to this account which can only be done with a brand account.  As such, I need to upload to a channel controlled by the brand account.

Answer (score 0):

Oops, miss conception on my part -- you don't need to use the brand account's client_id and secret.  You can use your own account's oauth details as long as you explicitly pass them in while creating the refresh token.